# How to get this path to work for any machine that has .m2 directory?

Tags: maven

I have written a mojo to extract a zip file. (There is a reason why I am not using maven-dependency-plugin to extract it). I have a path for a zip file in my Mojo and it is hard coded.

```
String zipFilePath = "/home/<my-username>/.m2/repository/mytest/template/app/mytest-template-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mytest-template-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip";
```

This zip is there in my .m2 directory and it's details are as follows.

```
group id = mytest.template.app
artifact id = mytest.template.app
version = 1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I have create the zip file name taking the `artifact-id + version`

How can I modify this file path to get dynamically by taking the .m2 folder dynamically in the machine that this code is running?

(I am using Ubuntu.)

Comment: I can use ${settings.localRepository} in maven to get the .m2 repository. Is it possible to use the same in java ? If so how can I use it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a Mojo, this is the way to do it:

```
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

   @Parameter( defaultValue = "${settings}", readonly = true, required = true )
   org.apache.maven.settings.Settings settings; // Using FQCN for clarity.

   @Override
   public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException  {

       getLog().info("My repo is at " + settings.getLocalRepository());

   }
```

As a side note, your `artifact id = mytest.template.app` doesn't translate to `mytest-template-app` since dots in an `artifactId` are not interpreted in same way as `groupId`.